# Do CardLayout, GroupLayout, nullLayout all allow preferred size for its component (Java GUI)?

Tags: java, user-interface, layout

Do CardLayout, GroupLayout, null layout all acknowldge the preferred height and width of a component?

Comment: Why don't you write a quick test?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

Most of them squish everything around, and make it really hard to work with. If you are planning on creating a GUI I recommend using MigLayout, as this allows complete control over every aspect of all components.

From what I've found, the native Java LayoutManager's are garbage. MigLayout takes a bit of learning, but in the end is the most flexible and easiest to use.

[Get it and look into it HERE.](http://www.miglayout.com)

[DISCLAIMER: This is mainly my opinion. I am not saying that other LayoutManagers are impossible to use and that you shouldn't use them, nor am I saying that MigLayout is the best. All LayoutManagers can create stunning results, but some take more work than others to use.]